# Site with dynamic component change, by scrolling the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, scroll

What tools can be used to create scrolling behavior like the one on this site: https://yuga.com/ ?

I tried to use a lock on the sections, waiting for them to scroll fully horizontally.
After I finished scrolling, I returned the ability to scroll the page

```
const screenLock = (entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[]) => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 790) return;

    const event = entries[0].isIntersecting;
    if (!event) return;

    if (!props.ignoreFixed) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setFixed(true);
            document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
        }, 100)
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

so what you are looking for is called "Parallax".
There actually is a library for that called "react-scroll-parallax", here is the link for it's npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-parallax

It's very simple to use, I've previously used it in some projects and it looks great. There also is a great documentation page with a few examples you could follow and refer to.
https://react-scroll-parallax.damnthat.tv/docs/intro

Hope this helps :)